# Wamp + Laravel 5.1 + Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, laravel-5, wamp

Alguém já configurou o Laravel 5.1 para rodar no Wamp usando base de dados postgresql?

Tenho uma instalação do Laravel rodando em um servidor WAMP, porem ao rodar o comando "php artisan migrate"eu recebo o seguinte erro:"[PDOException]could not find driver". Todas as minhas configurações do Laravel estão corretas, e já teste uma conexão para verificar se instalei corretamente o postgresql e também esta tudo certo. Segue abaixo minhas configurações e testes, se alguém puder me dar uma luz fico agradecido:

// database.php

```
'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'pgsql'), ...

'pgsql' => [
        'driver'   => 'pgsql',
        'host'     => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset'  => 'utf8',
        'prefix'   => '',
        'schema'   => 'public',
    ],
```

---

.env

```
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=postgres
DB_USERNAME=postgres
DB_PASSWORD=postgres
```

---

teste_psql.php

```
<?php
$dbconn = pg_connect("host=localhost port=5432 dbname=postgres 
                  user=postgres password=postgres")
      or die('Não foi possível conectar: ' . pg_last_error());
echo 'Conectado: ', pg_dbname($dbconn);
?>
```

Comment: Verifique no phpinfo se o driver do pgsql está instalado.

Comment: Esta sim, esta tudo habilitado, PDO drivers: mysql, pgsql, sqlite, PostgreSQL(libpq) Version  9.2.2 PostgreSQL(libpq)  Uninitialized version string (win32)
Multibyte character support  enabled
SSL support  disabled
Active Persistent Links  0
Active Links  0  pdo_pgsql
PDO Driver for PostgreSQL enabled
PostgreSQL(libpq) Version  9.2.2
Module version  1.0.2
Revision  $Id$

Comment: Engraçado a mensgem de erro diz, que php_pdo_pgsql não está instalado ...

Comment: Não, diz que não encontrou o driver. Mesmo eu tentando uma conexão PDO direta via TINKER o erro é o mesmo: $DBH  = new PDO("pgsql:host=localhost;port=5432;dbname=postgres;user=postgres;password=postgres"); PDOException with message 'could not find driver'. Este mesmo código quando rodado no php puro funciona normalmente

Comment: Você habilitou a extensão pdo_pgsql no php.ini ??

Comment: Já habilitei tudo que tinha pra habilitar.... mas ai resolvi o problemas usando o Vagrant(https://www.vagrantup.com/)

Comment: Valentim Araújo - Poderia explicar como uso o Vagrant para solucionar o seu problema por favor.